# Modules as function arguments

Tags: python, module

I have a python script that starts with importing a python module that contains data. A very simplified example is given below:

**my_data1.py**

```
bar = 10
baz = [1, 5, 7]
...
```

**my_func.py**

```
from my_data1 import *

def foo():
    '''
    function that uses the things defined in data (scalar, list, dicts, etc.)
    in my_data
    '''
    return [bar] + baz
```

This works great for one set of data; however, I have `my_data1.py`, ..., `my_data36.py`.

**my_data36.py**

```
bar = 31
baz = [-1, 58, 8]
...
```

that I want to import and then run `foo()` with that data. I wanted to do something like this:

```
def foo(my_data):
    from my_data import *

results = []
for i in range(1,37):
    results.append(foo('my_data{}'.format(i)))
```

This doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: I could import the specific data from `my_data` if that makes it feasible, but I haven't been able to figure that out either.

Comment: Yes and no. Each of the 36 have the exact same data names with different values (i.e. `my_data1` has `bar= 3`, `my_data2` has `bar=10` and `foo()` uses `bar`)

Comment: Why not get the "data" by reading and parsing a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__). It takes a string as parameter identifying the module to be imported, and returns the module, which then you can pass as an argument to your functions.

```
def processDataSet (module):
    print (module.baz)

for m in ['data1.py', 'data2.py', 'data69.py']:
    processDataSet (__import__ (m) )
```

Answer (score 1):

"from module import * is invalid inside function definitions." from http://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#inside-function-definitions